# How to show progress in dock icon?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, programming, ubuntu-dock, gtk3

How can I show application progress in a dock icon?

My native GTK3 application which runs on Ubuntu has an icon that appears in the the Ubuntu dock when the application is running. The application preforms a task and displays a progress bar.

Is there a API or Ubuntu dbus interface that my application should send messages to, in order to also show the progress overlaid on its icon in the dock?

Nautilus is a good example of what I want to achieve. While copying files in Nautilus, the Nautilus icon in the Ubuntu dock has an overlay icon that shows the progress of the copy process:

[image: Nautilus icon in the dock with progress overlay]

Note: I expect this to work on Ubuntu 20.04. (But it would be nice if it also works in 18.04 LTS, although I don't remember if 18.04 supported this capability).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dash of Gnome Shell currently has no API to allow displaying progress bars. It would not make sense with the default setup of Gnome, where the Dash is only visible when actively summoned in the Activities or Applications view, but would obviously make sense in extensions like Dash to Dock. This is discussed in this [old issue report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=701402#c13).